# How to test api calls using fetch

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, mocking, fetch

I can't find a definitive answer on what the proper way to unit test `fetch` is online. I'm using the `create-react-app` build. so far this is the closest I've found where a user recommends using `nock` & `node-fetch`. I have seen some development on a library here: https://github.com/wheresrhys/fetch-mock but it's build is failing which makes me nervous.

Goal is to make this play nicely with `jest`

Does anyone have any recommendations from experience on the best way to test request using the fetch api?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `fetch-mock` like you linked to test the new fetch api calls.

The fact that the build is failing means absolutely nothing to you. This is just for the devs to know when committing to github for continuous development. When you use `npm i --save-dev fetch-mock` it will download a (hopefully) working release version that the github author specifically publishes, not the failing build.

Example from my project for a redux thunk action:

```
import expect from 'expect';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import fetchMock from 'fetch-mock';

import * as actions from './formActions';

const mockStore = configureStore([thunk]);
const store = mockStore({});
const body = {
  email: 'test@gmail.com',
};

describe('registerFormActions', () => {
  let calledActions;

  beforeEach(() => {
    store.clearActions();
    calledActions = store.getActions();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    fetchMock.reset().restore();
  });

  it('should post form', () => {
    fetchMock.postOnce('/account/register', body);

    store.dispatch(actions.submit()).then(() => {
      expect(fetchMock.called('/account/register')).toBe(true);
    });
  });
});

export const submit = formData => dispatch =>
fetch('/account/register', {
  method: 'post',
  body: formData,
  credentials: 'same-origin',
}).then((response) => {
  if (response.ok) {
     // Do something cool
  }
});
```

Comment: Hm, good to hear from someone else that has used it then. I'll go ahead and push forward with that.. thanks, was afraid of going down a rabbit hole.

Comment: No problem. I'd just take a look at the documentation next time, if it looks like what you need then no reason not to use it, especially for unit tests that aren't production code.